# Is there a way to use emoji's in android webview apps?

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, webview, emoji

I created an android webview app.
Part of the app is a messages system.
When I send an emoji as a message or as part of a message the emoji disappears it is not inserted into the database.
I checked how it is received from the client side and it looks like gibberish `▒^▒^▒^▒`.

I'm using html and javascript for my client side.
And using php and MySQL on my server side.
My database tables are all `CHARSET=utf8;`.

I'm sending the message text in an ajax request with these headers:
`xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`.
I'm using `FormData` to send the entire message form.

I'm using `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />` in my html.

What am I missing? How do I make it work?
I couldn't find an answer so far nor a similar question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `utf8mb4` with MySQL in order to be able to store Unicode codepoints outside the basic multilingual plane (BMP). Most emojis are located outside the BMP.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html